# using wpf how to enable "enter" key press for a button placed inside a popup

Tags: wpf, button, popup, wpf-controls, enter

I am facing a problem though it might have a simple solution but was not able to find it out.

I have a page (say mainPage) with several buttons inside that on which I enable "Enter" key-press for one button (say Submit) by setting the IsDefault="true" in xaml for that button and it worked fine.

Clicking on the other buttons on my mainPage will open a popup which contain 2 buttons "Yes" and "No". setting IsDefault="true" property for "Yes" will not work when I press enter. (for information it will not work for the Submit button as well and that is also not a problem and I think I have a [solution](http://neilmosafi.blogspot.in/2007/04/default-buttons-in-wpf-and-multiple.html) for that as well )

how should I enable this feature for the buttons in popup?

(for more info we have a button which create a popup that have button and textbox inside that.in that case setting IsEnable="true" for button inside the popup will do the job for the button but only if we click on the textbox.
I tried setting focus on the textbox after observing this behavior so it might help but setting focus on the textbox does not work. use to set focus on textbox like this:
Focusable="True" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textboxName}"  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set focus on your `Popup` first so it can respond to the `Enter` key

There are two types of Focus in WPF: Keyboard and Logical. You can have multiple objects with Logical focus providing they're in different Focus Scopes (for example, you can have one element focused in your Window, and another in your Popup), but only one object can have Keyboard focus.

To set focus in a Popup, I usually just use the `Loaded` event which executes anytime the Popup becomes visible and loads.

```
MyTextBox.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
Keyboard.Focus(MyTextBox); // Set Keyboard Focus
```

**Edit**

Sometimes if something else in your application is stealing focus right after the `Loaded` event, you can use the `Dispatcher` to run your Focus code at a later [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), such as `Input`

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
    new Action(delegate() { 
        MyTextBox.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
        Keyboard.Focus(MyTextBox); // Set Keyboard Focus
     }));
```

Comment: Hi Rachel,
thanx for your answer. will try this tomorrow and m sure it will work.I am new to WPF , but m sure there might be other ways to do that as well, and as i said I have popups with no textbox in it so dont want to add unnecessary hidden textbox particularly for this purpose. I would be happy if you share some other ways as well :)

Comment: @SohailAnwerFaruqui You can set Focus to the `Button` if there is no `TextBox` on the Popup

Comment: Thanx Rachel, I think there is some issue with my project which is not allowing me to set the focus where I want.
I tested these keyboard and logical focus on a dummy project with same layout and it does work.

Comment: @SohailAnwerFaruqui Can you edit your question to include the code for your dummy project so we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Rachel,
well the dummy project had simple controls, and the focus works fine on them.it had a textbox and a button which pressing it will open a popup which had again a textbox and button and both the button set as a default buttons and the textbox inside the popup gets the focus once the popup opens using the keyboard focus.(though the logical focus also works).
thanx for your precious time and guidance. :)

Comment: @SohailAnwerFaruqui Oh, sorry I misread your previous comment and thought you said it *didn't* work. See the update to my answer as an alternative you may be able to use in your case.